# Ajax cannot call python function from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, function

I cannot call the following function in a .py file from a javascript.

For context: I am running a .py file with flask in a virtual environment. The html page mentioned within the .py file launches as it should on a localhost. Everything else within the page works as it should. Except that I cannot get a list i need from the .py file.

This is what my ajax call in my javascript looks like (I actually had this at the end of another javascript function that works fine, putting the whole thing here didn't seem necessary as I believe the issue is with this ajax call and not with the function it is under):

```
$.getJSON('/api/',
    function() {
    listMaker()
  });
```

This is what my .py file looks like (I have simplified the function returning the list, it is more complex but would take up too much space. The jist of it is that i need it to return a list):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") # implements the basic "root" / controller
def main():
    return render_template("testPage.html")

@app.route('/api/', methods=["POST","GET"])
def listMaker():
    return[1,2,3,4,5,7]
```

Just in case the ajax script i am calling is wrong, here is a look at it in my html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have seen several similar questions on here and have tried using their methods/advice. But for whatever reason, regardless of what i try, it does not seem like my ajax call to the python function is working. Any and all advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You need to debug the response from the AJAX request. Look at the console in dev tools and check if there's any errors. Also check the network tab in there to ensure the status code is 200 OK and the response text is what you expect it to be. Also note that your JS code is not handling the response at all. It just calls the client-side `listMaker()` function when the request completes without providing any of the retrieved data

Comment: @Rory Hello! I'm very new to all this and do not fully understand what you mean by "not handling the respinse' what does handling the response usually look lik?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the docs, it gives a much clearer description and example than I can :) https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson